# custom memstr (strstr) speed optimisation

Tags: c, performance, pointers, arm, strstr

I am writing a routine to find a string within a specified block of memory in an embedded (ARM Cortex M0 @16MHz) application and am wondering why the two different versions I have written run at different speeds.

```
char* memstr(char* mem, uint32_t n, char* str) {

    if( (str[0] == '\0') || (n == 0) )   return NULL;

    uint32_t i = 0;
    char* max_mem;

    max_mem = mem + n;

    while( mem < max_mem ) {
        if( *mem != str[i] ) {
            mem -= i;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            if(str[i+1] == '\0')   return mem - i;
            i++;
        }
        mem++;
    }

    return NULL;
}


char* memstr2(char* mem, uint32_t n, char* str) {

    if( (str[0] == '\0') || (n == 0) )   return NULL;

    uint32_t c = 0;
    uint32_t i = 0;

    while( c < n ) {
        if( mem[c] != str[i] ) {
            c -= i;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
            if(str[i] == '\0')   return &mem[c - i + 1];
        }
        c++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

memstr is consistently a 1us faster than memstr2 when finding a 7 character string in between 20 and 200 bytes of memory. For example finding a 7 character string in 110 bytes, memstr takes 106us and memstr2 takes 107us. 1us may not sound a big deal but in an embedded application where every tick matters it's a drawback.

Kind of a bonus question: This also prompted me to write my own strstr which is faster than stock strstr (e.g. finding a 7 character string in a 207 character string takes my_strstr 236us and strstr 274us). What's wrong with this though as strstr must be pretty optimised?

```
char* my_strstr(char* str1, char* str2) {
    uint32_t i = 0;

    if( str2[0] == '\0' )   return NULL;

    while( *str1 != '\0' ) {
        if( *str1 != str2[i] ) {
            str1 -= i;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
            if(str2[i] == '\0')   return (str1 - i - 1);
        }
        str1++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: With your last function, I think `my_strstr("sssmith", "ssmith")` returns `NULL`, which is wrong.

Comment: Mooing Duck: Good spot, I have fixed that

Comment: What does your disassembly look like? Having just compiled them myself, there doesn't look to be any particularly notable difference between the two routines (in fact `memstr` is slightly bigger and has one more branch than `memstr2`, which might normally position it to be the slower one), but obviously _my_ compiler says nothing about _your_ performance. Furthermore does your micro have any flash or RAM wait states (i.e. are instruction fetches, data accesses, or both more expensive than expected)?

Comment: Sorry Notlikethat, I am using an online compiler which hides the assembler from me. Not very helpful for speed optimisation I acknowledge.

Comment: Depending on the searched pattern length, and how the string is searched (i.e., always same string in a varying buffer? Or vice versa?), have you considered using a more complex algorithm such as Boyer-Moore? [ http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html ]

Comment: Thank you Iserni. Both strings are changing each time I use the routine so an approach that relies on a constant string would not help. I will take a closer look at Boyer-Moore though.

Comment: The difference between your measurements is less than 1%, which might easily be a statistical error. Plus, how exactly do you benchmark these functions? Are you sure that your clock has that 1us resolution? Oh, and yes. You've changed the code several times but haven't updated your measurements.

Comment: Hi Nikita, I did remeasure when I made the `mem -= i;` edit and was surprised to see no change in the times. The other edits were done to both functions so wouldn't change the delta.

Comment: @user1228123 if you look at the source for most `string.h` functions, you will find they are optimized to handles memory and character string of any length (generally though loop unrolling, etc.). Your comparison with strings of `20` - `200` bytes will parallel the `string.h` performance, but will rapidly under-perform as length/size increases.

Comment: @Nikita Kakuev to time the function I used a ms accuracy timer to time a for loop of 1000 calls to the respective function. I ran them through a few times to check for statistical variance, but don't expect it as the timer is clocked of the HF source as is sysclock.

Answer (score 0):

First, both functions don't work if you search for a string starting with two equal characters: If you search for xxabcde and the string contains xxxabcde then when you notice that that a of xxabcde doesn't match the third x, you already have skipped two x's and won't match the string.

You also don't check whether you search for an empty string, in which case your code produces undefined behaviour.

You compare memory with memory. But you can do an awful lot of work just comparing memory with a single character. If you search for "abcde", first you have to find the letter a. So I'd check for an empty string first, then read the first character. And then first loop to check for that character.

```
char first = str2 [0];
if (first == '\0') return mem;

for (; mem < maxmem; ++mem) if (*mem == first) {
    ... check whether there is a match
}
```

You should check your data. You would write different code if you expect the search string to come up early vs. if you expect it usually not to be there at all.

Comment: Thank you gnasher729. You beat me to my edit to rewind in the case that Mooing Duck pointed out with my_strstr which was also a bug in memstr and memstr2. To generalise the function I must add a line to each to cope with zero length strings.

Answer (score -1):

In memstr 'mem' is used as a pointer.  In memstr2 'mem' is used as the name of an array 'mem[c]'.  Depending on optimization a compiler might multiply by 1.

For instance in the statement:

```
if( mem[c] != str[i] ) {
```

mem[c] is calculated each time through the loop as

```
* ( &mem[0] + c * sizeof(mem[0]) )
```

A decent compiler would figure out that for a 'char' the sizeof(mem[0]) == 1 and the muliply could be skipped.  If optimization were intentionally disabled as is typically done for debug versions I can imagine an extra multiply operation per loop.  There would be a little extra calculation time in the memstr2 version even without the multiply, but it would surprise me if that were measurable.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that the difference can be due to the fact that in the second version you dereference the pointer (`return &mem[c - i - 1];`) when you return from the function which can lead to access in memory which is costly and is something that can not happen in your first function (`mem - i`).
But the only way to be sure is to see what assembly is being created for each case.
I don't think this is about C but about compiler and platform

Comment: Thanks Jim, so you think the consistent difference is in the return statement.

Comment: I think that you need to check the assembly created for these 2. I suspect that they are not the same and there is some load instruction happening. These are not defined in the C standards. They are implementation details although they appear equivalent

Comment: @Jim What pointer do you think he dereferences? `&mem[c - i - 1]`and `mem + (c - i - 1)` are precisely the same, right? (I think you're basically right. It's just that there's some extra math in calculating the address to return, not that there's an extra memory access.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:They are the same for us but may be not for the compiler. May be besides the extra math some load instruction is added and the value is ignored.